# Raspberry pi 2 blinking ACT LED at boot

Tags: boot

My pi recently crashed out of the blue and now it won't boot at all. The screen has a blank input. The ACT LED is flashing 7 times and the PWR LED is solid on. Any help? Can't find anything around Google about this many times flashing leds.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: it happened to me as well, couldn't do much! took a backup from the SD card and wrote the image back to it. 5 minutes and i was back online.

Answer (score 4):

As my answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41450/raspberry-pi-not-working/41455#41455) says, the amount of blinks the ACT light makes determines the reason your RPi isn't booting. (I'm assuming that you are using Raspbian and that your power supply is sufficient and that you've checked your sd card for corruption and a few other things because your question did not specify anything other than the ACT LED flashes 7 times.)

7 Blinks means that `kernel.img` isn't found.

To fix this, read your sd card with another computer and check that `kernel.img` is in the `boot` partition of the card. If it is not, you may be able to extract another Raspbian image and place `kernel.img` into the partition.

If it is in your `boot` partition, and/or replacing it does not work, you may be out of luck. Backup anything that you can then reformat and reinstall Raspbian on the card.

Comment: You beat me to the answer by 10 hours. That was a close one :)

Comment: @PandaLion98 Photo finish!

Answer (score 0):

There at too many report of SD card damaged when active on a sudden power loss.  Without a orderly shutdown, you  have a very high probability of data loss. [(1)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/is-my-raspberry-pi-permanently-damaging-sd-cards?s=1%7C1.0998) Just search for 'damaged SD'; some empiric reports go as high as 5% of the time!!

There is no single recipe to fix this problem and what area may be damaged is unpredictable.

You may save most data and perhaps, recover the full system, following one or more of the following steps.

- Setup a system on new SD card using the **same** procedure you use with the original you want to recover.
- Get a USB SD card reader (Amazon, eBay or you favorite one). There is a SD card sold with a free SD to USB adapter.
- Mount the card on the reader and plug on the <kbd>RPi</kbd> USB hub.
- Using `ls /dev/sd*` find the damaged SD card just mounted, it will show as `/dev/sda` or perhaps `/dev/sdb`.

  > ```
  > ls /dev/sd
  > 0 brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 2016-06-20 22:02 /dev/sda 
  > 0 brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 2016-06-20 22:02 /dev/sda1 
  > 0 brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 2016-06-20 22:02 /dev/sda2
  > ```

<sub>If your are using 'Jessie' the memory will be automatically mounted. Check with `df`; if this is the case you may not need the next few steps.</sub>

Explore the SD finding which partitions are ok and which one are damaged.
using fdisk /dev/sda1'

> ```
>  fdisk -l /dev/sda
>
>  Disk /dev/sda: 28.8 GiB, 30908350464 bytes, 60367872 sectors
>  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>  Disklabel type: dos
>  Disk identifier: 0x6f92008e
>
>  Device     Boot  Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
>  /dev/sda1         8192  131071  122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
>  /dev/sda2       131072 2658303 2527232  1.2G 83 Linux
> ```

<sub>The configuration will be different if you started with NOOBS.</sub>

If you reach this point and no hard sector failure you are in good shape to continue.

- In this case you have two partitions, `/dev/sda1`, type FAT32, the boot partition and `/dev/sda2` type Linux. (yours may be different)

  - To mount the first one, create an empty directory and mount the partition:

> ```
>  mkdir /mnt/sda1
>  mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
> ```

- Check the content with `ls /mnt/sda1` and compare the listing with your (new) running unit: should be the same content than `ls /boot`. If not the case, just copy the missing files.
- If you have data to recover, mount the 'linux' partition, replacing 'sda1' by 'sdb2' and follow the previous mount procedure. Then, you can scout and recover your old files copying them to your running system.

About the blinks: the green light also blinks when the SD card is active. Default green led use is [mmc0]:

> ```
>  cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger 
>  none [mmc0] timer oneshot heartbeat backlight gpio cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3 default-on input rfkill0 phy0rx phy0tx phy0assoc phy0radio
> ```

*Boot blinks* and other useful info are described [here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Power_.2F_Start-up), but some information is deprecated.

**pd:** `sudo` omitted for brevity.