# How do I stop HDMI powering my Pi?

Tags: power, hdmi

I have my pi 2 running Kali 2.0.1 which is hooked to a 7in tft sun founder screen. The problem is that when unhook in micro USB port to power the pi is still running  so in order to turn my pi off I have to unhook the hdmi and micro USB so shut my pi down.

Comment: Is the pI realy still running or is the monitor just displaying the last received image?

Comment: Wait. What? Wha... Why? I don't think HDMI can power anything*. I agree with @Havnar. The display may just be displaying the last image received from the Pi.

Comment: Does the Pi itself still light up (red light on the pi) with only the HDMI cable connected?

Comment: the pi2 still works as if the micro usb was still in i can browse the web run commands and everything else u can think of i can do with the hdmi powering the pi.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's all about the red light. You can issue the `sudo shutdown -h now` command and when you see `system halted` message it is safe to turn it off by removing USB. [Taken from here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/381/how-do-i-turn-off-my-raspberry-pi). Not a bad idea is to add a button to the pi that will power on and off the device. Then add a shutdown script to turn the power led off `echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led1/brightness`. This will not tell you the exact turn off moment but will turn off the led.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your monitor has the newest HDMI, that can power a device connected to it. The new HDMI format supplies 5v to a pin. How to turn it off is beyond me. Maybe check the monitor's manual.

Comment: It is true that [an HDMI source (e.g. a Raspberry Pi) must supply at least 55mA on the 5V line to the sink (e.g. a TV or monitor)](http://www.hdmi.org/learningcenter/kb.aspx?c=13#42), but I can not find any reliable information anywhere that _the sink (e.g. a TV)_ can/does provide _the source_ (e.g. a Raspberry Pi) with power. What specification (or article) says that "the new HDMI format supplies 5V to a pin"?

Comment: The only specification I can find which supplies power over a video cable is [MHL (Mobile High Definition Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link#Versions). This interfaces with HDMI, and several manufacturers (including Samsung) have shipped devices supporting this standard.