# Raspberry Pi 3 Freezes

Tags: chromium, shutdown, crash, corrupt, reboot

My Raspberry Pi 3 Model B freezes randomly. This as been going on since I got it, about 4 months ago. It sometimes freezes on reboot causing reboot loops. It freezes on Chromium when all that's open is 1 Chromium tab. The CPU has 100% usage, when only a single Chromium tab is open in the foreground. Every time it freezes I only have one apparent option — To pull the plug. However based on [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/381/74353) post, pulling the plug can corrupt the SD card. I have tried so far:

- Check the system log — Nothing out of line.
- Re flash the image — Didn't work.
- Check for background processes — the only way I know is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> like in Windows's Task manager system — I didn't find anything that seemed off to me though.
- Look for known errors on GitHub and search through the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange — found nothing pertaining to the actions of my error.

**If this helps anyone help me solve this issue:**

---

- I am running an Apache 2 server on port 80

---

- Lighttpd on port 8888

---

- Nginx on port 8976

---

Any other ideas or possibilities? Is it at all possible to fix this? I can not just force stop something because it froze.

## Updated and additional information:

- The Pi freezes sometimes on other operating systems. I have OSMC and Raspbian, they are more common on Raspbian but still happen on OSMC.
- The CPU seems to overheat as well for some reason, it does say 100% CPU full, but from what? Only one Chromium tab is running in the foreground. The PI is hot to the touch. I do have 2 heat sinks on it as well.

  ## Update: Example when it is frozen: 1 termanal window, thats not even running code right now:

[image: Example of when my pi frezes!]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I/O failure is a common cause of this; processes suffering from such are
stuck in an [uninterruptible sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call)#Uninterruptible_sleep).

If this is widespread and includes critical processes, the entire system will stutter and stall -- although from a GUI perspective this may be exaggerated in that it is mostly the GUI that is stalling.

Such processes can be identified with diagnostic tools like `ps` and `top` since their state will be indicated as `D`.  Of course, that's hard to do if the user interface has become unresponsive, but presuming the system log itself is working, there should be copious evidence left referring to I/O errors with a block device (e.g., on the pi, `/dev/mmcblk0p2`).

Although it can't be done decisively with an SD card device as it can with a spinning disk, you should try putting the card in another computer and running:

```
e2fsck -cvf /dev/[whatever]
```

Where `[whatever]` refers to the root filesystem on the card, generally the second partition.

The `-c` flag will do a read check on each block.  With an SD card this is abstract (which is why it is not decisive as with a spinning disk), so you cannot prove the card is *good*, but you can prove that the card is *bad*. This may be via direct reporting from `e2fsck`, or it may be because `e2fsck` gets stuck in a `D` state; run `top -p/-C` to monitor it and check it occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

According [the official doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md)

> The Raspberry Pi 3 is powered by a +5.1V micro USB supply. Exactly how much current (mA) the Raspberry Pi requires is dependent on what you connect to it. We have found that purchasing a 2.5A power supply from a reputable retailer will provide you with ample power to run your Raspberry Pi.

Please check whether your power supply is powerful enough.

Comment: my power supply is 2.5A from kanakit

Comment: I have Canakit 5V 2.5A supplies and they're the best ones I've found in the sense that I've had contexts drawing a lot of current and they were the *only* ones which worked, out of a pile of 4 or 5 different kinds.  So you are probably good there.

Comment: Raspberry pi works fine with 2.5 Amp. But 3.0 A is officially recommended

Comment: I have had one vilros and one canakit powersupply fail in the last two years, on pi's that run 24/7.  Neither failed suddenly, but progressively supplied less and less voltage and or current until the lightning bolt, and then erratic.  I run peripherals off of powered usb hubs.  The only items plugged into the pi 3b+ and pi 3B usb ports directly are wireless keyboard dongle and the usb hub.  The pi3B occasionally has an SDR dongle direct, since the software is not happy going through a usb powered hub.